# How to insert a polynomial between two continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

Let $f,g\in C[0,1]$ such that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Show that there exists a polynomial $p\in C[0,1]$ such that $f(x)<p(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

I know that I have to somewhere use Weierstrass Approximation Theorem in order to prove the above statement but I really am not able to get the idea. Please someone give me any hint or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, let $$h(x)=\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2},\, \varepsilon=\frac{\min|f(x)-g(x)|}{2},$$ then apply [Weierstrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) for $h(x),\,\varepsilon$.

Comment: Yep... just take the average....